# Maya callback when renderLayer's renderable attribute changed

Tags: python, callback, maya

I'm looking to create an OpenMaya callback when the specific attribute "renderable" is changed on an render layer in the scene. I tried this:

```
import os
import time
from maya import cmds, OpenMaya as om

dag_path = om.MDagPath()
selection = om.MSelectionList()
selection.add("defaultRenderLayer")
selection.getDagPath(0, dag_path)
m_obj = dag_path.node()

def callback(message_type, plug, other_plug, client_data):
    if not message_type & om.MNodeMessage.kAttributeSet:
        return

    if "renderable" in plug.name():
        print("renderable changed!")

job = om.MNodeMessage.addAttributeChangedCallback(m_obj, callback)
```

But Maya spits out an error on "selection.getDagPath(0, dag_path).
I am not experienced using OpenMaya or callbacks, but I would appreciate any help I can get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I remember *defaultRenderLayer* is not a DAG node, so you should use `getDependNode` on the selection:

```py
selection = om.MSelectionList()
selection.add("defaultRenderLayer")
m_obj = om.MObject()
selection.getDependNode(0, m_obj)
```

To double-check, this should print `defaultRenderLayer` as node name:

```
node = om.MFnDependencyNode(m_obj)
print(node.name())
```

Comment: Thank you man, you're a legend. Works perfectly.